# Preventing DLL injection in jpackage generated EXE

Tags: java, windows, dll-injection, jpackage

As the title states, is there a way to prevent DLL injections in jpackage generated binaries? I have created an EXE for a JavaFX application. During security testing of this application, it was noticed that arbitrary DLLs can be loaded during execution of the application.

Some remediation steps were mentioned such as:

- Use of `SearchPath` to identify location of library or component
- Use of `LoadLibrary` to identify OS version
- Use fully qualified paths for all `LoadLibrary`, `ShellExecute` and `CreateProcess` calls where possible
- Implement calls to `SetDllDirectory` with an empty string to remove current working directory from default DLL search order where required
- Sign executable files and verify signature before executing EXE or DLL files

If my code used any of the above calls directly, I could control it. But is there any way to control these after the files have been generated?

P.S. I use JDK 16 and the [Badass Runtime Plugin](https://badass-runtime-plugin.beryx.org/releases/latest/) to generate the EXE via a Gradle task